# Odoo 9 Is there a way to put default records into a tree view when Create button clicked?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, auto-generate

I'd like to create a tree view with default records.

So when I click "Create" button It shows a form view with a tree view below.

And It generates default records on the top of the tree view, then a user can put another records below.

Is there a way to do this?
I cannot find such a function in Odoo when I look into core source.

**Edited for some code**

```xml
<record id="test_task_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">test.task.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">test.task</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Groups">
                <sheet>
                    <group col="4">
                        <field name="task_id"/>
                        <field name="user_id"/>
                        <field name="date"/>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page name="Timesheet list" string="Timesheet">
                            <field name="timesheet_ids" widget="one2many_list">
                                <tree string="Timesheet Description" editable="top">
                                    <field name="description"/>
                                    <field name="time"/>
                                    <field name="difficulty"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I'd like to auto generate timesheet records at a tree view with description and time that stored somewhere.

Comment: put some code of your own. or some code that you want to understand

Comment: @CherifOdoo I've edited to add some code for people to understand

Comment: here you are using one2many or many2many relation, so you have to create or write records to your list. else this cant be seen under the page. Better would be show your script so I can give you any solution.

Comment: Did you try to use the `default` argument in the definition of your field?

Comment: Default argument is for new records. What i want to do is to add 2-4 existing records to the top of the column automatically